# Can I pass an object of a superclass in the invoke method while traversing through the methods of subclass via Java Reflection?

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection, invoke, superclass

So let say I have a Person class which is the super class--> looks something like this:

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String adhaarID;
    private int employeeID;


    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String adhaarID, int employeeID) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.adhaarID = adhaarID;
        this.employeeID = employeeID;
    }

    public Person() {
    }

    public String getFullName()
    {
        return firstName+" "+lastName;
    }


    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }



    public String getAdhaarID() {
        return adhaarID;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public int getEmployeeID() {
        return employeeID;
    }


}
```

And I have a sub class Employee which extend class Person and have no new method (other than what Class Person already have). In the worst case it gonna have all the methods that class Person have.
In all its method the class Employee calls its super methods:---> looks something like this:

```
public class Employee extends Person {

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String adhaarID, int employeeID) {
        super(firstName, lastName, adhaarID, employeeID);
    }
    public String getFullName() {
        return super.getFullName();
    }
    public String getAdhaarID() {
        return super.getAdhaarID();
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return super.getLastName();
    }
    public int getEmployeeID() {
        return super.getEmployeeID();
    }
}
```

Now I am traversing through all the method of Class Employee through java Reflection.
and I have Class Person object named person.
I am passing that object to invoke the method. Like lets say getAdhaarID of Employee class is invoke on person then the value stored in person object should be returned.
How should I do it. This does not work (see below):

```
Class<?> clazz = Employee.class;
    Method[] arrayOfMethods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
    for(Method method : arrayOfMethods)
    {
        String methodReturnValue = method.invoke(person,null).toString();

    }
```

This given an error Person cant be cast to Employee.

Comment: That's normal. Just think of it like this: Every Employee is a Person, not every Person is an Employee

Comment: But How to do that?

Comment: I only want the methods which are in the employee class to be called on person object??!!!

Comment: why do you even have those methods in your Employee class?

Comment: I'm so confused. Why do you override the methods of your superclass, with a call to that same method in the superclass? Why would you use java reflection in the first place to call these methods? You can cast an object of type Employee to an object of class Person. Then the method of the Person class gets executed directly.

Comment: Actually this is just an example I have created to explain the actual scenario I am facing. It may not logically make sense here in this example, but in my case it really does make sense to do all this, trust me. So please help me with the scenario and mention if there is any other way to do the same that I am trying to do here?

Comment: In general you cannot call methods defined in one object on another (non-subclass)object. This is because the methods in question may rely on undefined fields.

Comment: Why can't you create a static method on Employee which takes a Person class as a parameter?

Comment: `Method superMethod = Person.class.getMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes()); superMethod.invoke(person);`